# Getting chart information from nvd3

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I have a number of nvd3 charts on a page, and I store some useful information in the chart's id attribute (basically a rowkey that I used to populate the data).

What I want to do is fetch additional data when the user clicks a point on the graph.

The problem is, with many graphs on the page, when the user clicks (I have registered for lines.dispatch.on('elementClick')), I need to somehow know which graph I am on so I have the information I need to make the subsequent query.

Is there some way to grab the containing chart information when the user clicks on a point? Or knowing the chart's ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `jquery` on your page, then you can use [`jquery.closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to look for the parent `chart` element and extract its ID:

```
.on('elementClick', function (d, i) {
    var chartId = $(this).closest('svg').attr('id');
    // ...
});
```

Comment: While this didn't get me 100% there it did get me on the right track. I opted to do something like: var self = this; var cb = function(e) { ... }; chart.lines.dispatch.on('elementClick', cb.bind(self)); So now I have access to parent object in the nvd3 callback.